# DB call in each row of dataset<row> in java

Tags: java, postgresql, apache-spark

hi I'm trying to db call in each of dataset in java. But it keeps to occur this error.

my question are two things:

1. Is this a unusual way of db call?
2. Does it exist other solution?

This is the code I tried:

```
public class SparkSql implements Serializable{

     public void wordAddress(String word) {

      Dataset<Row> recent =sparkSession.read().format("jdbc")
                           .option("url","jdbc:postgresql://"+ip+":"+port+"/"+db )
                   .option("driver","org.postgresql.Driver")
                   .option("query", sql)
                   .option("user", user)
               .option("password", passwd)
                   .load();
     recent.foreach(x->{
            String temp = x.get(1).toString();
            Dataset<Row> old = this.oldAddress(temp); -->another DB call in the method like above 
                System.out.println(old.count())
```

This is the error log:

```
ERROR] 14:06:53.789 Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.HashAggregateExec.<init>(HashAggregateExec.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.AggUtils$.createAggregate(AggUtils.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.AggUtils$.planAggregateWithoutDistinct(AggUtils.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkStrategies$Aggregation$.apply(SparkStrategies.scala:419)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:63)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:435)
```

Comment: although I've answered the likely issue it'd be good if you mention the version of Spark being used and the full stack trace, I _assume_ somewhere in there it will refer to your source code in oldAddress where you use sparkSession.

Comment: Spark stacktraces can be _very_ voluminous.  Unfortunately the entire stacktrace can contain information.  There will probably be additional lines "caused by" that contain further stack traces.  Please try to attach all of them, or at least go over them and look for some reference to your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create new Dataset's or use the SparkContext/SparkSession from executors, they only exist on the driver node.

Your foreach is being passed to executors where you are trying to create another dataset, the function which is captured includes the reference to the SparkSession.

To perform lookups across databases using Spark you need to create the two Dataset's first and then join them.

Comment: Like you said, I used sparkSession in oldAddress function and It was the problem. I should create another dataset and join it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: yw, you should accept the answer so others can find it